# Symfony inteface based constructor dependency injection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm .NET developer and have some questions about Symfony's IoC implementation.
Does Symfony is capable for .NET-style (i.e. Ninject, Castle Windsor, etc.) constructor injections. Namely, can I avoid the necessity of giving name to each service and bind service implementation to interface instead? Also can I do not define each controller as a service for make DI working? "Controller as a service" and manual configuration constructor's parameters in services.yml(xml) seems to me redundant after years of .NET development. Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Namely, can I avoid the necessity of giving name to each service and bind service implementation to interface instead?

No, you can't. It one of the things I'm missing in the di component too.

> > Also can I do not define each controller as a service for make DI working?

The good point about symfony2 is that it removed most of the convention-based things. Doing the thing you suggested adds a mew convention to symfony. You could check the KnpRadBundle, to see how they implemented auto registering of other services, based on conventions and create your own bundle which does it for controllers.